# Does the order of the route written on route file affects how auth middleware is applied in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I wrote a nodejs router file with several routes then I had the following as shown

```
// GET route to retrieve all cycles for a specific admin
router.get("/:adminId/cycles", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { adminId } = req.params;

    const admin = await Admin.findById(adminId);

    if (!admin) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Admin not found" });
    }

    const cycles = admin.cycles;

    res.status(200).json(cycles); // Return the cycles in the response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Delete a cycle
router.delete("/:adminId/cycles/:cycleId", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { adminId, cycleId } = req.params;

  try {
    const admin = await Admin.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "cycles._id": cycleId },
      { $pull: { cycles: { _id: cycleId } } },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!admin) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Cycle not found" });
    }

    res.json(admin);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server Error" });
  }
});
```

And I wrote the following route (sendpasswordlink) below the above routes first and tried sending a post request then I get 'msg: No Token found, Authentication failed' -when there's no auth middleware applied to it.

```
router.post("/sendpasswordlink", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const { email } = req.body;

  if (!email) {
    res.status(401).json({ status: 401, message: "Enter Your Email" });
  }

  try {
    const userfind = await Admin.findOne({ email: email });
    console.log("userfind" + userfind);
    // token generate for reset password
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: userfind._id }, config.get("jwtSecret"), {
      expiresIn: "120s",
    });

    const setusertoken = await Admin.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: userfind._id },
      { verifytoken: token },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (setusertoken) {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: email,
        subject: "Sending Email For password Reset",
        text: `This Link Valid For 2 MINUTES http://localhost:3001/forgotpassword/${userfind.id}/${setusertoken.verifytoken}`,
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("error", error);
          res.status(401).json({ status: 401, message: "email not send" });
        } else {
          console.log("Email sent", info.response);
          res
            .status(201)
            .json({ status: 201, message: "Email sent Succsfully" });
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ status: 401, message: "invalid user" });
  }
});
```

However moving the sendpasswordlink route above the auth routes gives me a valid response - ie no token issues, I was wondering why it is the case, do we have such a rule that when auth middleware is applied to a specific route it will by default apply to all the routes written below it even though its not explicitly added to the route

Comment: check if you have any Application level or router level middleware ?http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application